# WmiMonitorRawEEdidV1Block no longer works in Windows 10

Tags: windows, wmi

After the major November Update of Windows 10 the monitor WMI functions are no longer working, especially the **WmiMonitorRawEEdidV1Block** is returning "not supported", I have tested this on 2 computers with the same results (it worked with the initial release of Windows 10 and older Windows versions also work).

Tested with DisplayPort, HDMI connection and on a laptop.

Windows 10 build 10586

Namespace root\WMI

Is there a new WMI method in Windows 10 to retrieve the Monitor EDID information ?

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed.  No obvious reason that I can see, this tends to be driver trouble but I don't have any issue getting EDID data from the plug & play api.

Which is your alternative right now, you can get sample C# code from [this project](https://edid.codeplex.com/), sample C++ code is available on [this page](http://ofekshilon.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/).

Comment: Thanks, but my app uses only WMI functions to be able to work remote in a network.